# Add Jquery libraries to Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

Could someone please point me on how to add Jquery libraries to Selenium? I did search online and below are the steps I have followed so far. I am not sure what to do next. After these changes, how do I build the selenium jar back with the changes?

1. Unzipped selenium 2.04.jar
2. Copied contents of jQuery.js in user-extensions.js
3. JQuery locator to the Selenium core in the runSeleniumTest() function of the selenium-remoterunner.js file like below,

   function runSeleniumTest() { 
           ... 
           selenium.doAddLocationStrategy("jquery", " 
       var loc = locator; 
       var attr = null; 
       var isattr = false; 
       var inx = locator.lastIndexOf('@');

   ```
   if (inx != -1) { 
       loc = locator.substring(0, inx); 
       attr = locator.substring(inx + 1); 
       isattr = true 
   } 

   var selectors = loc.split('<'); 
   var found = $(inDocument); 

   for (var i = 0; i < selectors.length; i++) { 
       if (i > 0) {found = $(found.parents()[0]); 
   } 

   if (jQuery.trim(selectors[i]) != '') 
       found = found.find(selectors[i]); 
   } 

   if (found.length > 0) { 
       if (isattr) { 
           return found[0].getAttributeNode(attr); 
       } 
       else { 
           return found[0]; 
       } 
   } 
   else { 
       return null; 
   } 
       "); 
       ... 
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update a file in a jar, refer [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/basics/update.html).

Essentially:

> The basic command for adding files has
>   this format:
>
> jar uf jar-file input-file(s) In this
>   command:
>
> The u option indicates that you want
>   to update an existing JAR file. The f
>   option indicates that the JAR file to
>   update is specified on the command
>   line. If the f option is not present,
>   the Jar tool will expect a JAR
>   filename on stdin. jar-file is the
>   existing JAR file that's to be
>   updated. input-file(s) is a
>   space-deliminated list of one or more
>   files that you want to add to the Jar
>   file.

You could perhaps also just add the JQuery js file as a Selenium user extension. Refer [here](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/08_user_extensions.html).

Just remember to start the Selenium RC server using the -userExtensions argument and pass in your user-extensions.js file.

> java -jar selenium-server.jar
>   -userExtensions user-extensions.js

Comment: Great..that worked...thanks so much..I am not using Selenium RC, mostly using WebDrivers and WebDriverBackedSelenium. I would think this should still work, right?

Comment: I've only ever used Selenium RC but give it a whirl and see.